# Log out from public server- how to secure my ship

Tags: space-engineers

When I build a ship on some public server, what happens to it when all of my faction are logged out?

Does it stay in the game? If so, how to protect it from other players while no one is around? Are there any strategies to secure the ship?

I wonder if it:

- Should stay in place or keep moving (slow or fast?)
- Use the auto pilot?
- ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the server, on some servers the time is stopping if no one is online. Nevertheless, your ship stays in the game.

You could:

- jump multiple kilometers using a jump drive (e.g. 100 km) in any direction, no one will find you there
- if the world size is limited, hide behind or, depending on the shape, in an asteroid
- use many turrets on your ship
- disable your beacon or antenna
- if you keep your ship moving the chance that players will see your ship is higher and it may crash in an asteroid, in addition you are unnecessary stressing the server
- if you have enough ressources, just build a huge base with lots of turrets and hide your ship there :)